# How to pass jwt token in ajax datatable header laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, jwt

hello i need help in laravel datatable, i get token in session but its not working, so how to pass in haeader in datatable ajax laravel, this is my working code. but its give me error Token is Required.

```
var token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
console.log(token);
//$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
 $('#kt_table_1').dataTable().fnDestroy();
 $('#kt_table_1').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    serverMethod: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': token,
    },
    ajax: '{{route('api-product')}}',
    columns: [
     {
          data : null,
          "bSortable": false,
          'render': function (data, type, row) {
            return '<button type="button" data-id="' + data.id + '" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Quick Edit">Edit</button>\t\t\t\t\t\t<button type="button" data-id="' + data.id + '" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Quick Edit">Delete</button>'; 
          }
      },
      { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
      { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your routes in the `api.php` or `web.php`. It is possible, it is asking for csrf_token. Please try passing token inside the object as

```
...DataTable({
    data: {
        "token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    }
    ...
});
```

If you are using Oauth and want to pass in JWT barrier token then please refer this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests

Apart from your solution I would recommend to use Axios  https://github.com/axios/axios to fetch the data first and then populating into Datatable because of pagination issue you might face in future (depending on your needs).

Comment: Thank you,
nocsrf token, i want to pass jwt token,